# PostgreSQL calculate rolling histogram with group

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, timescaledb

I have stock trading data in postgresql db with timescale.
I've calculate volume histogram by price (volume profile) for one day using such query

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
volume_profile_daily
WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
AS
SELECT FLOOR(close/1.00)*1 as close, 
       SUM(volume) AS volume,
       time_bucket('1 day', date) as date,
       asset
FROM trade_cgl

GROUP BY time_bucket('1 day', date), asset, FLOOR(close/1.00)*1
```

bucket range is 1.

Now I'm trying to calculate histogram with moving window (for n past trading days).

I'm able to calculate it foor particular day like this:

```
select close, SUM(volume) AS volume
from volume_profile_daily
where date in (select distinct(date) from volume_profile_daily
where date <= '2021-09-01'
order by date desc
limit 30)
and asset = 'ASSET_NAME'
GROUP BY close
```

Subquery returns last 30 trading days. Based on this I just create new histogram for 30 days period.

EDIT: I want to calculate 30 days period histograms for each day I have in database. Query with specific date is just example.

Is it possible to precalculate it and store in materialized view/table? I don't want to calculate it each time. It's hard for me to find out any general solution.

Comment: I'm confused by the histogram part of this? What do you mean by histogram here? I'm only seeing sums being computed?

Comment: Another question I have, why don't you want to calculate it each time? is it too slow? How long does it take to run? (We may be able to re-write the query slightly to get it to run faster).

Comment: @davidk it's grouped by price so it's gives me histogram for each day. Regarding second question: I have over 1400 assets since 2011. It will took to much time to analyze if I will compute this each time.

Comment: Are you getting it for a single date at a time or for all the dates at once?

Comment: @davidk For now I don't have proper query to get it for all the dates ;)

Comment: I added an answer that helps get that, you might want to modify your question a bit to clarify some of those things, let me know if I've helped answer what you want though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [TimescaleDB's continuous aggregates](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/create_materialized_view/#create-materialized-view-continuous-aggregate), since they cannot be defined on continuous aggregates, but you can use [PostgreSQL's materialized views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

I believe the following should work:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW volume_30_traiding_days AS
  select close, SUM(volume) AS volume
  from volume_profile_daily
  where date in 
    (select distinct(date) from volume_profile_daily
    where date <= '2021-09-01'
    order by date desc
    limit 30)
  and asset = 'ASSET_NAME'
  GROUP BY close
WITH DATA;
```

It will immediately run the query and materialized it.
If it will be necessary to refresh it, e.g., to include new data for the desired period, it is possible to do with [REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html). Note that it will recalculate the entire materializaion, and equivalent to dropping and recreating the materialized view.

If it will be necessary to do something more interesting than in the question, e.g., refreshing it regularly, I suggest to look into [TimescaleDB's user-defined actions](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/user-defined-actions/).

Answer (score 0):

Ah so the histogram is because we're looking at the closing price somehow and that is the bucket, okay. I think I kind of see what you're trying to do. You can calculate it the way you suggested, but it might be a bit inefficient, especially if you want it over longer periods. A window function would probably be better for something like that.

```
-- create your original continuous aggregate
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
volume_profile_daily
WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
AS
SELECT FLOOR(close/1.00)*1 as close, 
       SUM(volume) AS volume,
       time_bucket('1 day', date) as date,
       asset
FROM trade_cgl

GROUP BY time_bucket('1 day', date), asset, FLOOR(close/1.00)*1;

--now do a sum over the previous 30 days using a window function

WITH windowed as (SELECT *, sum(volume) OVER prev_thirty
FROM volume_profile_daily 
WHERE asset = 'ASSET_NAME'
AND date >= now()-'90 days'::interval
WINDOW prev_thirty AS (PARTITION BY close, asset ORDER BY date DESC ROWS 30 PRECEDING)) 
SELECT * FROM windowed 
ORDER BY date desc limit 30;
```

note that I use the where clause for now - 90 days in the first part of the query, that's to make sure that all the days that I want (the last 30 or so, which I get in the `SELECT * FROM windowed ORDER BY date desc limit 30`) have the correct amount of data, so I added a fudge factor as I am pretty sure that in order to get data for the last 30 trading days, I won't need data past the last 90 days. However, adding the where clause makes the view work much, much more efficiently under the hood as it doesn't have to go back too far in time - this saves a lot of time in its re-aggregation step. Otherwise it will do a lot of work to get a few values which is probably why the query is slowing down. So while you can't use the window functions directly in continuous aggs, they should give you enough of a cache to make this calculation pretty efficient, you just need to give them a query end so that they're limited in what they have to calculate.

Hopefully that answers some of your questions as we clarified in the comments and can help you get where you need to go, but feel free to ask more to clarify!